# Can I hide non-seas/oceans on Google Maps Styling API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am double checking, really, as I think the answer is no: Can I hide bodies of water which aren't seas/oceans, i.e. lakes. A client is commenting that these smaller bodies of water make the maps look "complicated".

Here's my styling rules:

```
fsdStyles = [
        {
            featureType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                {visibility: 'off'},
                {hue: '#00162b'}
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: 'administrative.country',
            stylers: [
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: 'water',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#002f56' },
                { saturation: 85 },
                { lightness: -84 },
                { visibility: 'simplified' }
            ]
        }
];
```

Comment: So by hide, do you mean show that area as land? If so, I'm not sure I like the implications and potential consequences of creating a map like that :)

Comment: Did the answer below help you? Its customary to click the arrow shape next to the answer, if you believe it addressed your question.

Comment: @jpm – yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot turn the features you describe off. And there is only the single feature type: `water`, there are no sub-types, so there is no real way to style lakes in one way and oceans in another.